# Openshift: How to create a scc with SYS_LOCK capability

Tags: openshift

When I want to see a `scc` details:

```
$ oc describe scc restricted 
Name:                       restricted
Priority:                   <none>
Access:                     
  Users:                    <none>
  Groups:                   system:authenticated
Settings:                   
  Allow Privileged:                 false
  Default Add Capabilities:         <none>    (1)
  Required Drop Capabilities:       KILL,MKNOD,SETUID,SETGID    (2)
  Allowed Capabilities:             <none>    (3)
...
```

I see that appears three sort of capabilities, `(1)`, `(2)` and `(3)`.

1. Which are the differences between them?
2. I need to create a `scc` setting up `IPC_LOCK` capability. Is `IPC_LOCK` a `drop capability`, or an `add capability`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By default, Docker allows capabilities, as described [here](https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/run/#runtime-privilege-and-linux-capabilities).

In OpenShift, the `restricted` SCC that you list above, disallows usage (*drops*) 4 of these, that's what the 'Required Drop Capabilities' is for -- you want to restrict containers more than the container runtime default.

An SCC can also add *more* than the default capabilities to a pod, by listing them under 'Default Add Capabilities'.

'Allowed Capabilities' is similar to 'Default Add Capabilities', except it doesn't provide the capabilities to all applicable pods automatically -- they must request the additional capabilities. If a pod requests a capability, and is being run by a user or group that has an SCC that allows it, then it will get it.

I think the above answers both of your questions. Here's what I'd consider (you're probably thinking something like this already):

1. Add `IPC_LOCK` to 'Allowed Capabilities' in a new SCC
2. Add the SCC to a Service Account to run your pod
3. Request the capability for the pod (or an individual container in a pod)

See the docs here for more (better!) information:

- https://docs.okd.io/latest/architecture/additional_concepts/authorization.html#security-context-constraints
- https://docs.okd.io/latest/admin_guide/manage_scc.html